# Pass values to agent page using node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have this code that gets values from the client website :

```
var server = ws.createServer(function(conn){
    console.log("New Connection");

    //on text function
    conn.on("text", function(str){

        /* here i was to take that value in the str and pass it to html file which is path "agent/index.html"*/

    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

I want to take that **str** value in the agent/index.html file and do something with it.

This **str** value came from a remote user website using **websockets** now I want this value to pass to the agent and this agent reply to it instantly, its a realtime chat application.

Kindly check the comments.

Comment: For using ajax, You can use express js and you can create a restful api.
For reference http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

Answer (score 1):

You got a bunch of options. Cookies, localstorage, URL parameters, POST the data and store it (probably not suggested).

If you only want the data for just that page, I would just use URL parameters. Inside your function, redirect the user to agent/index.html?text=str and on index.html, retrieve the URL parameter, and do what you like with it.

Comment: I want to pass it in real time and not refresh the page..
I am creating chat application

Comment: I'm not sure I full understand what you are trying to do. Are you on one page, but you want to send data that will be used once the user enters another page?